# Calling a Static Singleton Class from Junit test throws StackOverflow error

Tags: java, junit, static, singleton, stack-overflow

When We run the DrawerOpenTest.java it throws the StackOverflow error, while we expect the test case to be passed. And when DrawerOpen class is singleton, assertThat(actualState, is(expectedState));  Should be also true in test case.

Note that 'State' is interface with 3 basic methods.

DrawerOpenTest class

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class DrawerOpenTest {

@Test
public void openCloseButtonPushedPositiveTest(){
    DVDPlayer cut = DVDPlayer.getInstance(DrawerOpen.getInstance());
    State expectedState = DrawerClosedNotPlaying.getInstance();
    State actualState = cut.openCloseButtonPushed();
    assertThat(actualState, is(sameInstance(expectedState)));
}
}
```

DrawerOpen Class

```
public class DrawerOpen implements State {

private DVDPlayer player = DVDPlayer.getInstance(DrawerOpen.getInstance());

private static State state;

private DrawerOpen() {}

public static State getInstance() {
    if(state == null)
        state = new DrawerOpen();
    return state;
}


@Override
    public void openCloseButtonPushed() {
        player.close();
        player.changeState(DrawerClosedNotPlaying.getInstance());
    }

@Override
public void playButtonPushed() {
player.close();
player.play();
player.changeState(DrawerClosedPlaying.getInstance());

}

@Override
public void stopButtonPushed()
}

}
```

DVDPlayer Class

```
public class DVDPlayer {
private DVDPlayer() {}
private static DVDPlayer player = null;

private State state;

public State getState() {
    return state;
}

public static DVDPlayer getInstance(State stateParam) {
    //making it singleton
    if(player == null)
    {   
        player = new DVDPlayer();
        player.state = DrawerClosedNotPlaying.getInstance();
    }
    else 
        player.state = stateParam;
    return player;      
}

public void changeState(State newState) {
    this.state=newState;        
}
public State openCloseButtonPushed(){
    state.openCloseButtonPushed();
    return state;
}

public State playButtonPushed() {
    state.playButtonPushed();
    return state;
}

public State stopButtonPushed() {
    state.stopButtonPushed();
    return player.state;
}
public void open() {
    System.out.println("DVDPlayer is opening.....");
}
public void close() {
    System.out.println("DVDPlayer is closing.....");

}
public void play() {
    System.out.println("DVDPlayer is playing.....");
}   
public void stop() {
    System.out.println("DVDPlayer is stopping.....");
}
}
```

Result: It results the StackOverflowError as its keeps initializing itself. Please help how to get this test as positively passed.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
    at DrawerOpen.getInstance(DrawerOpen.java:13)
    at DrawerOpen.<init>(DrawerOpen.java:5)
```

Comment: "making it singleton" You're not actually guaranteeing these are singletons, except if you only use this in single-threaded code.

Comment: True that i require a singlethreaded model. Because the resource DVDPlayer cannot handle multithreaded model.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
public class DrawerOpen implements State {

  private DVDPlayer player = DVDPlayer.getInstance(DrawerOpen.getInstance());

  // ...
}
```

means that you will call `DrawerOpen.getInstance()` every time you try to create a `DrawerOpen`, because `player` is a member variable.

In order to create an instance in `DrawerOpen.getInstance()`, you've got to create an instance of `DrawerOpen`; but that calls `DrawerOpen.getInstance()` again, requires you to create a `DrawerOpen`, which calls `DrawerOpen.getInstance()`...

You can avoid this recursive call by assigning `DrawerOpen.getInstance()` to a static field:

```
public class DrawerOpen implements State {
  private static DrawerOpen INSTANCE = DrawerOpen.getInstance();

  private DVDPlayer player = DVDPlayer.getInstance(INSTANCE);

  // ...
}
```

However, there is then another problem, which is that you won't have assigned `INSTANCE` at the time you call `DVDPlayer.getInstance(INSTANCE)`, so you will end up calling `DVDPlayer.getInstance(null)`.

One way to solve this would be to call:

```
  private DVDPlayer player = DVDPlayer.getInstance(this);
```

However, this is an example of what is called *unsafe publication*, wherein you are leaking the `this` reference before the `DrawerOpen` class is fully initialized. This may lead to further unexpected problems.

---

Your code is a bit of a tangled mess. You should think carefully about why you are using singletons at all, because these don't seem like singleton properties to me.

For example, it's a bit dodgy you've got a "singleton" which depends upon a parameter: if you call the `DVDPlayer.getInstance` with a different `State` instance, you currently ignore the new state instance, and use the previous one. This would very likely lead to confusing or surprising behavior: I gave you *this* state instance, but the DVDPlayer is using *that* state instance.

Comment: thanks for above recommendation. But this does not solve the issues and the first part still gives the StackOverFlow error but adding second recommendation thows compiler error from getInstance() method of DVDPlayer(since we are removing static field)

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines:

```
private DVDPlayer player = DVDPlayer.getInstance(DrawerOpen.getInstance());

private DrawerOpen() {}
```

to this:

```
private DVDPlayer player;

private DrawerOpen() {
    player = DVDPlayer.getInstance(this);
}
```

This will get rid of the recursive initialization loop.

Explanation: `this` in a constructor refers to the object being constructed.  This is the singleton that *would be* returned by `DrawerOpen.getInstance()` ... if the object had been constructed at that point in the code.

Comment: DrawerOpen.getInstance() is a static but the constructor is not. So there is a compilation error.

Comment: What are you talking about?  1) There is no call to `DrawerOpen.getInstance()` in my proposed fix.  2) A constructor can call a static method!  3) My answer says to replace *two* specific lines.  Not three lines (or five).